# Access to property of a stored closure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I have a property that holds a UIView instance like the one in this class:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var myView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        let label = UILabel()
        view.addSubview(label)
        return view
    }()
}
```

Is there any way I can access its `label` property from the view controller?

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    // myView declaration goes here
    func changeLabel() {
         myView.label.text = "Help!"
    }
}
```

The compiler tells me that `UIView` doesn't have a `label` member which is true. Is there any way to actually change the label text of the closure declared above?

Comment: you could create a custom class that extends `UIView` and set `myView` to an instance of that class. This new class could have a label and then you could get the label from your custom class instead of the `UIView`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Hamish. It has been fixed now.

Comment: @Cesare Okay, but now `myView` isn't a stored closure – it's a property that holds a reference to a `UIView` instance.

Comment: Thanks @milo526. That works! Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll +1. Not sure if it's the best approach though.

Comment: Thanks @Hamish for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view only has one subView, such as the one in the example that you are using, it's really easy to achieve by using the `subviews` property. This returns an array of `UIView` (in this case it will have only one element) and there you can find your label and change the text.

If your view is more complex and has several subviews, this can get trickier, since you'll have to iterate through the subviews array and get the corresponding one. This would lead to the use of tags and may not be the best solution for complex situations.

Another solution would be to make a simple subclass of `UIView` where you add a method which can be something similar to `addLabel` and there you save a reference to that label in a property. Afterwards you can access it easily.

Comment: Though I think Sweeper's approach is incredibly clever (so obvious, and yet I didn't think of it until I read it), the suggestion that you make a custom `UIView` subclass is likely the most wise and flexible. Using `tag` or digging around in `subviews` is very fragile and spreads a lot of special knowledge through the code.  A class is simple and robust. Swift's class syntax is so lightlyweight, that there's really little reason to avoid creating the class.

Comment: Exactly! I always try to avoid tags due to that exact reason, it spread specific knowledge through code, and it generates solutions that are extremely coupled to the controller or wherever its used. A subclass of UIView that performs this would require 6 lines of code, can be reused elsewhere, and code is cleaner

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can!

First, your first code snippet does not compile, it should be changed to:

```
var myView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    let label = UILabel()
    view.addSubview(label)
    return view
}() // <- add these parentheses
```

Now, to access `label`, we need to give the label a `tag`, so do this:

```
var myView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    let label = UILabel()
    label.tag = 1
    view.addSubview(label)
    return view
}()
```

Now you can access the label in your VC like this:

```
let label = myView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
```

Comment: This is super smart. Thank you!